# how to start chrome --disable-impl-side-painting in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I'm having problems with my Selenium tests. Sometimes, I get "no such session" error in my Eclipse when I run my Selenium Test in a external server Jenkins.
I've read that the solution is starting chrome with option --disable-impl-side-painting.

Do you know how could I disable that option from my java Selenium test??

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-impl-side-painting");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope this helps